# How to run varnish as a non-privilege user?

Tags: compilation, installation, varnish

I need to run varnish as a non-root user. Here is what I'm actually doing:

```
wget https://repo.varnish-cache.org/source/varnish-4.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzf varnish-4.0.2.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/home/neuquino/varnish
make
make install
```

But, when I run `varnishd` command I get the following error:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Not running as root, no priv-sep
```

It seems to be something with VCL compiler. Is there any option I should pass to the `./configure` or `make` commands to be able to run `varnishd` as a normal user?

I'm looking forward to find something like `./configure --user=neuquino`, but I can't find such option in the configure file.

Comment: How are you running `varnishd`?  The varnishd manual suggests that you can run varnishd with a `-u` flag to specify a non-root user.  I'd be surprised if this was a compile-time issue. (https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html)

Comment: That message about priv-sep is not an error but a warning, as you are launching varnishd as an unprivileged user varnish is not able to use privilege separation as a security measure, see: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/run_security.html#vcl-programs. If it's not starting there must be another problem.